# MultiSelectList problem, getting right type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with getting items in a multiselect to get selected.

I have this:

```
BookingObject bo = _bs.GetBookingObjects(bookingobjectID.Value).FirstOrDefault();
bo.BookingViews.Load();

MultiSelectList BookingViewsBookingObjects = new MultiSelectList(_bvs.GetBookingViews(), "BookingViewID", "BookingViewName", (IEnumerable<BookingView>)bo.BookingViews.ToList());
```

BookingViews <-> BookingViewsBookingObjects  <-> BookingObjects

Its a many to many relationship. _bvs.GetBookingViews() returns IQueryable of BookingView, and I cant seem to get the items from bo.BookingViews selected.

What might be missing here? am I using the wrong type?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to send the actual selected value in the last parameter the "BookingViewID" instead of the `IEnumerable<BookingView>` as a hole `IEnumerable<object>` it will be an `IEnumerable<int>` if BookingViewID is int, something like:

```
MultiSelectList BookingViewsBookingObjects = new MultiSelectList(_bvs.GetBookingViews(), "BookingViewID", "BookingViewName", (IEnumerable<int>)bo.BookingViews.Select(a=> a.BookingViewID).ToList());
```

EDIT: Full Code.

SetUp the Data(Controller/ViewModel):

```
   List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> List = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();;
            List.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1,"Value1"));
            List.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2,"Value2"));
            List.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3,"Value3"));
            List.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(4,"Value4"));

            List<int> selected = new List<int>{1,2};

            ViewData["Multi"] = new MultiSelectList(List.AsEnumerable(), "Key", "Value", selected);
```

(View):

```
<%= Html.ListBox("MultiSelectList", ViewData["Multi"] as MultiSelectList)%>
```

The Result:

[alt text http://www.diarioplus.com/files/pictures/multiselectlist.JPG](http://www.diarioplus.com/files/pictures/multiselectlist.JPG)

Comment: Didn't work, same restult, it has count=1 but that item doesn't get selected

Comment: Updated the post, added the full example, hope it can help.